# How to change ellipse border color

Tags: wpf, vb.net

What is the required code to change the border color of an ellipse?

I've tried the following, but nothing happens:

```
If sheerit Mod 2 = 1 Then
     Dim trueBorder As SolidColorBrush = New SolidColorBrush()
     trueBorder.Color = Colors.Blue
     elip2.Stroke = trueBorder
End If
```

Comment: Not enough context. What is `elip2`? What is `trueBorder`? Where are these objects coming from?

Comment: Your mixing VB and C# in that code

Comment: Virtual basic code needed.
i have a Shape that i want to change her border color.

Comment: What is the Stroke Thickness??  Might it be zero?
As @CodyGray said, there's not enough context, but if you change the stroke of an object, you _usually_ have to perform some sort of refresh/redraw.

Comment: Is this really supposed to be ASP.Net? Looks more like WPF to me.

Comment: I'm sorry for the ignorance, I meant to WPF

Comment: The code is good. Make sure that the condition `sheerit Mod 2 = 1` is true and that the stroke thickness is not set to 0.